# Twitter bootstrap modal hide after fade in

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

HI i have problem with modal

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" style="text-align:center">
        <p>
            <ul class="thumbnails">
            <li class="span3" style="">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/260x180" alt="">
            </li>
            </ul>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is how i call modal

```
<td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Show poster</a></td>
```

and after clicking on link modal fade in and fade out without clicking on dismiss button. I have copy this code from their site, What is wrong in it ??

**Edit** ### SOLUTION ###
In modal source code file 
i have comment this function

```
 /* MODAL DATA-API
  * ============== */
 /*
  $(function () {
    $('body').on('click.modal.data-api', '[data-toggle="modal"]', function ( e ) {
      var $this = $(this), href
        , $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) //strip for ie7
        , option = $target.data('modal') ? 'toggle' : $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())

      e.preventDefault()
      $target.modal(option)
    })
  })
*/
```

And now works great

Comment: Maybe you have a javascript bind somewhere? Try to change id of your modal window and to remove classes **hide** and **fade**.

Comment: I have changed `id` but it didnt help, I also remove `hide` and `fade` but after that when page load modal is visible

Comment: If you've commented that function, than you truly have somewhere another javascript bind function.

Comment: @Oleg what function do U think about ??

Comment: I don't know exactly. Some function that binds click event. Because I have no problems with modal windows.

Comment: Also it would be better, if you post your edit part of the question as answer to show other users, that issue is solved.

Comment: Once I have post solution as anwser and someone wrote me to edit my first post :) so let it stay that way

Answer (score 3):

Commenting out something in the plugin source is **not** the right way to address the issue.  You are not using it properly.  If you want to disable the Data API you should do it this way:

From the [documentation](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/js):

> DATA-ATTRIBUTE API
>
> We believe you should be able to use all plugins provided by Bootstrap
>   purely through the markup API without writing a single line of
>   javascript. This is bootstraps first class api.
>
> We acknowledge that this isn't always the most performant and
>   sometimes it may be desirable to turn this functionality off
>   altogether. Therefore, as of 2.0 we provide the ability to disable the
>   data attribute API by unbinding all events on the body namespaced with
>   'data-api'. This looks like this:

```
$('body').off('.data-api')
```

> To target a specific plugin, just include the plugins name as a namespace along with the data-api namespace like this:

```
$('body').off('.alert.data-api')
```

If you don't want to disable that API (I don't know what JS you are including or writing yourself) and it still isn't working, post your rendered page code so we can see what else is going on and help you fix it the right way.